# Counting case-sensitive words in a string using C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to count how many unique and case-sensitive words are in string `s`. So far, I've transformed the punctuations into spaces and added each separate word (separated by a space) into a set. Since, `set` includes only unique elements, the following function returns `1`. However, it should return 2 since the string `s` has 2 case sensitive words (`ab` and `AB`).

How can I check the case-sensitivity of the words in string s?

```
bool isWordSeparator(char c) {
    return std::isspace(c) || std::ispunct(c);
}

int main() {
    string s = "ab\nAB!ab?AB:ab.AB;ab\nAB";

    transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [](char c)->char {
        if (isWordSeparator(c))
            return ' ';
    });

    istringstream iss(s);

    set<string> words((istream_iterator<string>(iss)), istream_iterator<string>());



    cout << "Number of Words: " << words.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here isn't really with case sensitivity. It's with the lambda you're supplying to `transform`.

You're attempting to replace the separators with spaces. Unfortunately, while you return a space if `isWordSeparator` returns `true`, you fail to return *anything* otherwise.

Change your `transform` to something like this:

```
transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [](char c)->char {
    if (isWordSeparator(c))
        return ' ';
    else
        return c;
});
```

...and chances of getting useful results will improve considerably.